# Is there a way to enter keystrokes into web application running in Internet Explorer based on a file selection in File Explorer

Tags: powershell, autohotkey, pywinauto

I am in the process of entering deposits from scans on a computer running Windows 10.

The scans have a straight-forward naming convention:

```
$<amount>_<check#>_YYYY-MM-DD_<invoice ID>_<other number>_<name and notes>.pdf
```

I would like to parse the currently selected filename into variables and then send them as keystrokes into the application running in Internet explorer;

```
<alt>
n
p
<tab>
<amount>
<tab>
<check#>
<tab>
<tab>
MM/DD/YYYY
click on a specific interface element to move to the next block
<tab>
<invoice ID>
<alt>
r
<alt>
a
<alt>
f
s
<alt>
f
x
```

What would be a suitable tool for this automation? On a Mac I'd just use AppleScript, but I'm not seeing anything as obviously suited. Candidates include pywinauto, Powershell, and Autohotkey --- not sure if I can get the others installed, by Powershell is installed and available.

EDIT:

Example filename:

$25_000123456_2020-11-02_1234567_9994321_John Q Public.pdf

The only browser on the table at this time is Internet Explorer.

Comment: This definitely looks like a problem that AutoHotkey can solve. Could you please provide an example of one of the filenames so that we can use it to test? Also, are you looking at the file names through the Windows File Explorer, and when you select you mean that the file is currently highlighted, or do you mean something else?

Comment: If you must use Internet Explorer I'd look into automating it via the COM-interface. If other browsers are an alternative Selenium could be the way forward (which like COM could be programmed through PowerShell). A search fo either "Internet Explorer COM Powershell" or "PowerShell Selenium" should get you on the right track. And if you get stuck post a new question when you have a specific problem that needs solving.

Comment: Added an example filename. Yes, currently selected file in Windows File Explorer (I envision opening the file in Acrobat, verifying it as okay to enter, then running the script).